# To create a dataframe with given dynamic company name for particular dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe with 12 columns of data, including columns like 'Company Name' & 'Date'.
Now, I need a dataframe that has 50 companies (Nifty Fifty) for a given quarter end date. and i need 50 rows for a given date specified.

Taking a smaller example:

For 31-12-2009, I want the data of the following 10 companies out of 100 companies which I have.

```
company_list_1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
```

Now, for the next date which is 31-03-2010, I have a new list of companies whose data I need.

```
company_list_2 = ['a','b','c','l','m','n','o','x','y','z']
```

I have such static 40 dates having 50 dynamically changing companies out of a data of 100 companies' data which i have.

[image: input data sample]

[image: Sample output for the first date]

I need output for 40 such date and company filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the `df.loc[]` function, in which you can pass both condition added by `&`. For instance, if you have data frame `df` and you have company list as `company=['a','b','c']` and want to filter on data `date=31-12-2009`then your code will be,

```
df.iloc[(df['company_name'].isin(company)) & (df['NDP_Date']==date)]
```

Be carefull with the paranthesis.